# Alternative to weightSum in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have four `TextView` items that I want to evenly spread in a horizontal line. This means that all the space in a line must be evenly occupied by the `TextView` items. Like this:

[image: Evenly spaced TextViews]

Previously, I used LinearLayout for this. I had the weightSum as 4 and assigned a layout_weight of 1 to each `TextView` item. However, this compromises on some functionality I want to implement in my app:

I want to put an `EditText` item under each of the four `TextView` items. The `EditText` items visibility will be set to INVISIBLE first, and then at the touch of a button, the EditTexts will become visible and the visibility of the Textviews will be set to INVISIBLE. This is only possible if I use RelativeLayout

So how do I use RelativeLayout for the four `TextView` items while evenly occupying all the space?

Comment: Why not use two LinearLayouts on top of each other inside of the RelativeLayout?

Comment: Yes that's what I did now and it's working thanks Uxonith and Tubor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. That's why you were using a LinearLayout as the 4 TextViews container.

Comment: Well, is there anything else I can do? Something other than RelativeLayout which will allow me to hide an EditText item under a TextView while still keeping the TextViews evenly spaced?

Comment: A LinearLayout is the best option, so far. The EditText can be hidden by setting its visibility to **GONE** (it won't occupy any space).

Comment: @AkshayDamle TableLayout can be used..also present with weight.

Comment: @Tobor Yes but when I press the button I want the EditText to appear at the very same position as the TextView it was hidden under.. How can I achieve that with LinearLayout?

Comment: You can swap the visibility of the TextView and the EditText. Set one to GONE and the other to VISIBLE. They should share the same layout_width and layout_height, as well as layout_weight values. Then you programmatically swap their visibility (let's say on the TextView click and when you are finished with editing)