# ScrollView is not working in Linearlayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Below is my `xml` some of layout is below which is not fit on screen so I have applied `ScrollView` on parent `LinearLayout` that linear layout is applied with **weight** but when I am trying to scroll that layout its not scrolling. Can any one suggest me where and what I am doing wrong why `ScrollView` is not working on weight `LinearLayout` ?

```
  <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        app:adapter="@{imageSlideradapter}"
                        app:currentItem="@{landingLoginViewModel.currentPage}"
                        android:addOnPageChangeListener="@{landingLoginViewModel.pageChangeListener}"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_land_spacing"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_padding_top"
                        android:text="@string/label_businesscard_title"
                        android:textColor="#3e4360"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/businees_card_textmessage_size"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

                    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                        android:id="@+id/indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top_15dp"
                        app:centered="true"
                        app:fillColor="#1ebad6"
                        app:radius="@{landingLoginViewModel.pagerIndicatorCircle}"
                        app:pageColor="#c6caca"

                        app:snap="false" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5x">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonbackroudnd"
                        android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onSignIn()}"
                        android:text="@string/label_sign_in"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />


                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signin"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonborder"
                        android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onSignUp()}"
                        android:text="@string/label_sign_up"
                        android:textColor="#00becc" />


                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/oRtextLabel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signup"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5.5x"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/label_or"
                        android:textColor="#8998a7"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"

                        />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearlayout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/oRtextLabel"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onFacebook()}"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5x">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                            android:src="@drawable/fb_icon" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_1x"
                            android:text="@string/label_fcebook"
                            android:textColor="#465892"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                            android:textStyle="normal"

                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview and weight are two apart things. If you are using scroll view just use margins to set your views.

Comment: can u please tell me what margin we have to put it @ADM

Comment: This will depends on what exactly you need to design . Use RelativeLayout for reltive views. and use dimen.xml for margin dimensions to support all screens .

Comment: yes i want support all screen

Comment: how to know you Srollview is not working because for above design its not reach bottom of screen  ?

Comment: some of icon like facebook icon is hide at bottom

Comment: scroll view works only when view is out of the screen.If you give weights how will view go out of screen?Remove the weights for RelativeLayout

Comment: my view is aslo going out of screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ScrollView** is working, please check below layout

Note : changed widgets, heights and paddings and have fixed height for RelativeLayout to check ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="label_businesscard_title"
                android:textColor="#3e4360"
                android:textSize="5dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingTop="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="label_sign_in"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signin"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="label_sign_up"
                android:textColor="#00becc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oRtextLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="label_or"
                android:textColor="#8998a7"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/oRtextLabel"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="label_fcebook"
                    android:textColor="#465892"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/7yJbDcqirjAMkgL2gsxSyw  please check i have use same code

Comment: @ManojKumar no it is not same code. use my code and tell me if not working

Comment: you mean to say that we have to remove weight from relative layout correct ??

Comment: weight some in relative layout will not work it is just for linearlayout

Comment: in relative layout weight never work it is just for linearlayout

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626126/how-to-use-weightsum-in-relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xml with this one:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                app:adapter="@{imageSlideradapter}"
                app:currentItem="@{landingLoginViewModel.currentPage}"
                android:addOnPageChangeListener="@{landingLoginViewModel.pageChangeListener}"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_land_spacing"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_padding_top"
                android:text="@string/label_businesscard_title"
                android:textColor="#3e4360"
                android:textSize="@dimen/businees_card_textmessage_size"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top_15dp"
                app:centered="true"
                app:fillColor="#1ebad6"
                app:radius="@{landingLoginViewModel.pagerIndicatorCircle}"
                app:pageColor="#c6caca"
                app:snap="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5x">


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonbackroudnd"
                android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onSignIn()}"
                android:text="@string/label_sign_in"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonborder"
                android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onSignUp()}"
                android:text="@string/label_sign_up"
                android:textColor="#00becc" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/oRtextLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5.5x"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/label_or"
                android:textColor="#8998a7"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/oRtextLabel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onFacebook()}"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5x">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                    android:src="@drawable/fb_icon" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_1x"
                    android:text="@string/label_fcebook"
                    android:textColor="#465892"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Buddy I tested this on my machine its working :). Please dont forget to mark this post as answer if this works for you. I tested it you are good to go with this. Happy coding :)

Comment: not working dude i dont know why wait let me check in another device

Comment: i dont know why its not working in my side i am using databinding is that reson or what?

Comment: @https://paste.ofcode.org/7yJbDcqirjAMkgL2gsxSyw  M.Saad  Lakhna please check this i have use same code

Comment: I dont think so databinding is causing issue

Comment: I am not sure why this is not working... This should work